# Authenticated Devise root with username

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

If a user is logged in with Devise, I'd like to redirect them to their Posts index.

`/username/posts`

According to the [Devise docs](https://rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper:authenticated)
I can use an `authenticated` block.

```
authenticated :user do
   ....
end
```

But I need the user's username to redirect there. Something like this.

```
authenticated :user do |user|
   get '/', to: user_posts(user)
end
```

But this is not supported.

How to redirect with the current user to an authenticated root?

Edit:

NOT trying to do a `after sign in` Devise path. Trying to achieve a permanent root for logged in users and one for logged out users.

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def after_sign_in_path_for(user)
        user_posts_url(user)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do something like this
in your routes:

```
#config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {
    ...
  }

  authenticate :user do
    namespace :users do
      ...
      root :to => 'posts#index' # /users/posts # this will only be accessible to login users
    end
  end

  root :to => 'pages#index' #/pages this is accessible to all people
end
```

you will need:

```
#app/controllers/user_controller.rb
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
end
```

and

```
#app/controllers/users/posts_controller.rb
class Users::PostsController < UserController
  def index
    @posts = current_user.posts
  end
  ...
end
```

I hope that this helps